# What wrong with my ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to pass some list to my view through ViewModel. I have rebuilt my project several times to no avail. I have checked online, nothing different from my approach.

[image]

```
namespace sportingbiz.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class MatchesViewModel
    {
        private List<MatchViewModel> _matches = new List<MatchViewModel>();
        public List<MatchViewModel> Matches
        {
            get { return _matches; }
            set { _matches = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Markup

```
@model IEnumerable<sportingbiz.Models.ViewModels.MatchesViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<table style="width:100%">

@foreach (var item in Model.Matches)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Team1Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

If I remove the `.Matches` from the `foreach` it works.`Matches` does not show in the intellisense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your model is `IEnumerable<sportingbiz.Models.ViewModels.MatchesViewModel>` which is a series of MatchesViewModels. You need to enumerate that list first before you can call `Matches`. If you're only returning one MatchesViewModel, change your model declaration to:

```
@model sportingbiz.Models.ViewModels.MatchesViewModel
```

**Edit** - A trick I use often is to hover over any of the instances of `Model` and VS will tell you what *type* the model is.

Comment: I wouldn't notice that if not pointed out. I actually used a ViewModel before and changing it, I didn't realise I have to remove the IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

IEnumerable does not contain a method called Matches.  So naturally, trying to reference it won't work.

It's like taking a bag of chips and trying to get a chip by grabbing the bag, rather than reaching inside the bag.

I don't think you want to pass an IEnumerable of your viewmodel to the view.  I think you just want to pass the view model itself.